# prevent executing code directly from address bar

Tags: java, servlets

This is a code `BooksController?deleteBId=240` that will request to delete a row from a table. When I press delete `button` from a page, JavaScript confirmation dialogue box will appear where I can click `Yes` or `No`. It is helpful if I had accidentally pressed the delete button. But, If I execute directly from address bar by hitting enter, the confirmation box will not appear and the row will be deleted. Is there any way to prevent this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, implement this as a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request, not a GET.

Any HTTP action that can have a server side effect, should be POST (or possibly DELETE, but that's rarely used). GET should only be used for requests without any side effects.

More info on POST vs GET from W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

In HTML POST request are usually made by [submitting a form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) whose method attribute is set to POST. You can have JavaScript trigger the submission.

Comment: Additional notice: read also about CSRF protection, because POST request can also be provoked by attacker.

Comment: Works great. I wasn't using form but using as <a href="BooksController?deleteBId=240">Delete</a>. Now, I have modified and put inside form.